# DotNet 5 ClickOnce missing Assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, clickonce, .net-5

I am trying to distribute a program in our small business environment. I tried to choose therefore ClickOnce in Visual Studio 2019 and DotNet 5. However, if I open the EXE from the published folder, it tells me that a DLL is missing. After adding this one, it tells me another DLL is missing, aso. In contrast, if I publish to a local folder, everything works as expected.

What may I do wrong? It seems like the missing DLLs have something to do with PowerShell automatization (`Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`) which as I understood is only available as either x64 or x86. I tried to restrict my program to x64, however, without any success.

If you know any other simple distribution method for a small business (all pcs conneted locally) I am very happy and thankfully.

Comment: Did you try to include(not include(Auto)) the dll in "Application Files"?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. Missing dependencies can be added here, during the setup for ClickOnce export creation.

[image]